# Glade-3.18.3 crash

Tags: gtk, glade

I have installed Glade-3.18.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04. But when I'm try to open it 
it shows the following message and the gladeUI window just flashed. Please help me fix the problem. I already have Glade-3.8.0 working in my computer.

GladeUI-Message: 1 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mode
GladeUI-Message: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
    GtkApplicationWindow    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-applicationwindow'

(glade:7776): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkBox.margin-end

(glade:7776): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkBox.margin-end
glade: symbol lookup error: glade: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_set_margin_start

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint. I installed 3 packages, don't know which one was missing, but it worked.

```
apt-get install libgtk3.0
apt-get install libmono-profiler-gui-thread-check
```

Note that `libgtk3.0` regex selected `libgtk3.0-cil` and `libgtk3.0-cil-dev`.

Comment: I ran an update on `libgtk3.0` and it looks like my Glade stopped crashing randomly. `apt-get install libgtk3.0`